# Error in lm.fit(x,y,offset = offset, singular.ok,...) 0 non-NA cases with boxcox formula

Tags: r, eval, lm

I am trying to run a boxcox transformation with the following code:

```
urban1 <- subset(ski,urban <= 4,na.rm=TRUE)
ski$gender <- as.numeric((as.character(ski$gender)),na.rm=TRUE)
urban1 <- as.numeric((as.character(urban1)))
x <- (ski$gender*urban1)
y <- ski$EPSI.
bc <- boxcox(y ~ x) 
(trans <- bc$x[which.max(bc$y)]) 
model3 <- lm(y ~ x) 
model3new <- lm(y^trans ~ x)
ski$EPSI. <- ski$EPSI. + 1
```

But I keep getting this error:

Error in lm.fit(x,y,offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 0 (non-NA) cases Calls:  ... eval -> eval -> boxcar -> boxcar.formula -> lm ->  lm.fit Execution halted

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure about the 2nd row? If there is missing value in your code, you replace your data with incorrect values. May I suggest you to convert your code in the [tidyverse, and especially dplyr](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/) universe?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The error message

> lm.fit(x,y,offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 0
>   (non-NA) cases

is generated by the `lm(y ~ x)` command when variables `x` or `y` (or both) have only NAs.
Here is an example:

```
n <- 10
x <- rnorm(n,1)
y <- rep(NA,n)
lm(y ~ x)

Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  0 (non-NA) cases
```

In your code I suggest to test (just before your `lm` commands) if one of your variables has all NAs using:

```
all(is.na(x))
all(is.na(y))
all(is.na(y^trans))
```

In my example:

```
all(is.na(y))
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: I am getting this error after removing all columns which are fully NA. Could there be an additional reason for getting this error?

Answer (score 5):

The error can be triggered by **NA's in your data** or **a bad transformation**

```
#From the mtcars dataset
mpg.reg3 <- lm(mpg ~ cylinders + displacement + horsepower + weight + acceleration + year + origin, data=Auto, na.action=na.exclude)
```

Notice the `na.action=` argument. Setting this to `na.exclude` will allow the `lm` function to ignore NA's in your data. Another option is `na.omit` which acts in a slightly different manner.

The other problem may be a bad transformation of your data- double check your interaction terms and manipulations.